# CGI with nginx getting 502 bad gateway error

Tags: web-server, nginx

I want to use my RPi to source some data wirelessly. I'm working from Derek Molloy's Exploring Raspberry Pi. Step 1: get nginx working. I wrote my own index.html file and can get to it over my local LAN. So nginx works. Now I want to add cgi capability so, eventually, I can write a C or C++ program to control a device and return data.

So I followed the instructions on P. 490-491 of Molloy's book, adding fcgiwrap and adding the necessary include line in Nginx default. I typed in the simple cgi script with nano. ./test.cgi gives the expected result. So when I query:

`192.168.1.135/cgi-bin/test.cgi`

the response is: `502 bad gateway`

This has to be a brain-dead simple problem, but I can't find anyone with exactly this issue. 502 bad gateway with Apache? Sure. But what 3 characters or directory settings or other simple stuff do I need to check? Thanks.

Nginx config file (with most commented-out lines removed):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/fcgiwrap.conf;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # root ~/data/www;
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html; 

    server_name _;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please check the error logfile. I'd recommend to run `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` in a terminal window, keep it visible, then reload test.cgi in your browser and read the logfile. Please add your nginx config file to your question.

Comment: "you should check if your CGI-application first announces the mime-type of the following content. For html this needs to be `Content-type: text/html`" [source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#nginx_configuration_2)

Comment: Fabian: It does announce the mime-type. I will edit in my nginx config file momentarily. I did the tail -f, and when the 502 error happened, the nginx error file didn't change. In fact, from all the 502s I've seen, NONE registered with nginx!

Comment: please add `/etc/nginx/fcgiwrap.conf`

Comment: and the result of `sudo netstat -aptln | grep nginx` (I think its a port issue, fcgi doesn't use 80)

Comment: Port 80 shows PID/Program name as 754/nginx -g daemon, and the 502 error persists. Ah, but configtest says configuration failed. If I comment out the /etc/nginx... line you suggested, config passes. That means that adding that line was done in the wrong place or with the wrong syntax. It's just that line with a ; at the end? Or does it need a command like listen or include? Thanks.

Comment: Clarification: I eventually want to use a program on the Pi to receive parameters and serve files. I was planning to do this with a C++ program. If CGI isn't the easiest way to do this, then I'm asking the wrong question!